# Should I use "-" in sub domain to separate two words?

Tags: seo, subdomain

Should I use "**-**" in **sub domain** to separate two words?

If I need to create sub domain called "blogging tips" should I use `bloggingtips.example.com` or `blogging-tips.example.com`?

Comment: Stop wasting your time to decide a SEO friendly domain name. It will impact only 0.00001%. **There are so many other good things to consider**. I rarely see such a domain name when I enter any blogging related query. You need to wake up bro.

Comment: It does not matter. Search engines use nGram methods to find terms within a string with or without word boundaries (a programming term) which would be a space or character typically used as a separator. Both will work exactly the same. Do what is best for users and do not waste a second on figuring out the minute details of SEO.

Comment: The question is which looks better to your users?   Which is easier to read?   Which will more users see as spammy?  Which is easier to type?   Which is easier to remember?  Does just using a keyword rich subdomain look spammy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It shouldn't matter one way or the other from the search engine perspective as most of them will be able to see `blogging tips` from `bloggingtips` or `blogging-tips`

As pointed out above, having the keywords in the subdomain will not significantly move your needle anyway.  So pick the one that looks best to your userbase and run with it.